# Display ManyToOne field in Symfony2 forms?

Tags: symfony

I am having two entity files one as user.php and another as usertype.php. now i want to display a login form with 3 fields viz username, password and usertype. the usertype will be a selection that will fetch data from usertype table. here is the code that i wrote inside user.php to create a manytoone field for usertype_id

```
/**
* @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Usertype")
*/
protected $usertype;
```

Below is my Form generation Code

```
class LoginForm extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('login', 'text', array('label'  => 'Username',));
        $builder->add('password');
    }
}
```

Now I need to add one more field to my form builder that will be a selection of usertype table.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```php
...
use Acme\YourBundle\Entity\Usertype;

class LoginForm extends AbstractType {

    public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('usertype', 'entity',
            array(
                'class' => 'AcmeYourBundle:Usertype'
                'label' => 'User Type',
            )
        );
    }
}
```

You can read more informations about [the entity field type](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html) wich will give you the options available for this type of field.

Don't forget to add a **`__toString()`** method to your model to tell the form builder what to display.

```php
namespace Acme\YourBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

class Usertype
{
    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->getName();
    }
}
```

Comment: Link to "the entity field type" has expired. Updated link is http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html

Answer (score 2):

There are other ways to do it, but you can try this:

```
$builder->add('usertype', 'entity',
    array(
        'class' => 'YourBundle:UserType
        'required' => true, // Choose if it's required or not
        'empty_value' => 'User type', // Remove this line if you don't want empty values
        'label' => 'Type', // You can put a label here or remove this line
    )
);
```

I hope it helped!

Answer (score -1):

http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/reference/forms/types/entity.html

property¶

type: string

This is the property that should be used for displaying the entities as text in the HTML element. If left blank, the entity object will be cast into a string and so must have a __toString() method.

Comment: Could you do a bit more than simply quote the docs?  That might make your answer a bit clearer.